# Whom did the Prophet divorce?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, source-identification, talaq

In the tafsir of [ibn 'Ashur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Tahir_ibn_Ashur) ([التحرير والتنوير](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=2795&idto=2795&bk_no=61&ID=2829)) of verse 33:6 I found a quote saying that our Prophet divorced a woman from Kindah before consuming the marriage.

My question is did he divorce any other woman? Has he taken back any during the 'idaah?

I'm looking for textual (qur'an and sunnah) evidences for such divorces and reconciliation!

Comment: Can you add the name of that tafsir in arabic?